# $http.get failing to retrieve data from PHP backend

Tags: php, html, angularjs

### AngularJS, PHP, and MySQL: changing ng-repeat data on ng-change

I'ven been working on a web-base system and `ng-repeat` seems to have error on duplicate keys and I don't know what to do. The selectall brand seems working fine but the php code I paste below seems doesn't work and the "track by $index". the code below only display infinite loop or rows in the table

html code

```
<div class="card-body p-0">
      <!-- DataTales Example -->
      <div class="card shadow mb-4" style="font-size: 0.75rem">
        <div class="card-header py-2">
          <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-green">Category of {{selectedBrand}}</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="table-responsive col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12"
               ng-disabled="disableTable">
            <table class="table-letters-lg table-hover" id="dataTable" width="0%" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
                <tr class="bg-gradient-primary" style="color: white">
                  <th>Category ID</th>
                  <th>Category Name</th>
                  <th>Category Code</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr style="cursor: pointer" ng-repeat="categories in prodcategory">
                  <td>{{categories.category_id}}</td>
                  <td>{{categories.category_name}}</td>
                  <td>{{categories.category_code}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

angularjs code

```
$http.get('database/prodcategory/selectallbrandname_category.php')
  .then(function(z){
    $scope.prodbrand_category = z.data;
});
                        
$http.get('database/prodcategory/selectallbrand_category.php')
  .then(function(y){
    $scope.prodcategory = y.data;
});

$scope.selectBrand = function() {
    if($scope.selectedBrand == "All Brands") {
        $scope.showAllCategoryList();
    }

    else {
        var b_name = $scope.selectedBrand;
        $scope.showBrandCategoryList(b_name);
    }
}
$scope.showAllCategoryList = function() {
    $http.get('database/prodcategory/selectallbrand_category.php')
      .then(function(response){
        $scope.prodcategory = response.data;
    });
}

$scope.showBrandCategoryList = function(brand_name) {
    $http.get('database/prodcategory/selectbrand_category.php', {brand_name: brand_name})
      .then(function(x){
        $scope.prodcategory = x.data;
    });
}
```

php code

```
<?php
    require_once '..\connect.php';
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $brand_name = $data->brand_name;

    try {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `prodcategory` INNER JOIN `prodbrand` ON `category_brandid` = `brand_id` WHERE `brand_name` = ?");

        $stmt -> execute([$brand_name]);
  
        $data = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }catch (Exception $e){
        echo $e;
        $pdo->rollback();
        throw $e;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data for prodcategory when the issue appears?

Comment: the showAllCategoryList function works fine displaying data on the ng-repeat (also without the "track by $index") since it is only to select all data on the prodcategory table. when I call the showBrandCategoryList, without the "track by $index" on the ng-repeat it send this error "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]", and with "track by $index" ng-repeat displays blank infinite rows on the table.

Comment: The php code above works fine by changing the "?" into an existing data from the databse without inputing data from the js code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the `$http.get` operations is malformed.

> ERRONEOUS
>
> ```
> $scope.showBrandCategoryList = function(brand_name) {
>     $http.get('database/prodcategory/selectbrand_category.php', {brand_name: brand_name})
>       .then(function(x){
>         $scope.prodcategory = x.data;
>     });
> }
> ```

The second argument of the `$http.get` method does not carry data, it carries the optional `config` object.

From the Docs:

> ## `$http.get(url, [config]);`
>
> - url  `string` Absolute or relative URL of the resource that is being requested
> - config (optional) `Object` Optional configuration object. See [`$http()` arguments](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-arguments)
>
> — [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - $http.get](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get)

Answer (score 0):

for hours of looking at the angularjs code. It seems $http.get method doesn't work so  I changed it to $http.post.

```
$scope.showAllCategoryList = function() {
    $http.post('database/prodcategory/selectallbrand_category.php')
      .then(function(response){
        $scope.prodcategory = response.data;
    });
}

$scope.showBrandCategoryList = function(brand_name) {
    $http.post('database/prodcategory/selectbrand_category.php', {brand_name: brand_name})
      .then(function(x){
        $scope.prodcategory = x.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: This is because a GET uses url params and has no content body in request which is what you are looking for when using `file_get_contents("php://input")`